# Using MEDIA hardware buttons in an Android app running in Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

I've successfully run my application in Chrome with **ARC Welder**. I want to use Play/Pause buttons on my MacBook inside my Application.

My application is responding the media buttons normally in Android like below. It is working on **Google TVs** and **Android TVs**. But not working on Chrome ARC.

I've also responding to space and enter buttons and they are working on Chrome ARC perfectly.

Here is the code I am using in my `Activity`:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SPACE:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NUMPAD_ENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
            playPause();
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP:
            sendOrderedBroadcast(BaseNotificationService.STOP_INTENT, null);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

How do you think it can be done? Is it possible? Can there be a workaround to support Play/Pause buttons?

Comment: On a whim, add some logging to your `default`, to see if there is anything sent to `onKeyUp()` for those buttons, albeit perhaps oddly mapped by ARC.

Comment: Already did it. It doesn't output anything on media button on key press. I am on chrome 42 on Yosemite

Answer (score 5):

ARC currently lacks a complete mapping to translate all keycodes we get through the Chrome PPAPI into their Android equivalent versions.

There isn't really a work around -- the keyboard event just won't go through since there is no translation for it.

Since I tracked down some specifics while looking into it, I went ahead and filed [this bug](http://crbug.com/477718) to track it. Feel free to star it.